# What is Dynamic Linking?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

Reading JVM-8 specification I am trying to understand what Dynamic Linking actually is.

> 2.6.3 Dynamic Linking
>
> Each frame (§2.6) contains a reference to the run-time constant pool
>   (§2.5.5) for the type of the current method to support dynamic linking
>   of the method code >>(1)<< . The class file code for a method refers to methods
>   to be invoked and variables to be accessed via symbolic references >>(2)<< .
>   Dynamic linking translates these symbolic method references into
>   concrete method references, loading classes as necessary to resolve
>   as-yet-undefined symbols, and translates variable accesses into
>   appropriate offsets in storage structures associated with the run-time
>   location of these variables >>(3)<< . This late binding of the methods and
>   variables makes changes in other classes that a method uses less
>   likely to break this code.

**(1)** What is the "type of the current method ?" is it the class in which the method is defined in or it is the methods return type ?

**(2)** "The class file code for a method" This here refers to the .class file in which the method is defined, right ?

**(3).1** "Dynamic linking translates these symbolic ... " can we say that "Dynamic linking" is the process of translating symbolic method references into concrete method references, loading classes ... etc. ?

**(3).2** What exactly is the difference between symbolic and concrete method references, probably it would be good to mention how a method is represented in memory ? 
**(3).3** "resolve as-yet-undefined symbols" what are these "as-yet-undefined symbols" ?
**(3).4** "translates variable accesses into appropriate
offsets in storage structures associated with the run-time location of these variables" I don't understand anything from this sentence.

Comment: No, it is not “good to mention how a method is represented in memory” as the specification is not supposed to say how it has to be implemented. The in-memory representation is up to the JVM. The “as-yet-undefined symbols” are the same symbols the preceding text is talking about, minus those symbols that might turn out to be already resolved, as the implementation has to remember them. “translates variable accesses into appropriate offsets in storage structures” becomes clear once you try to imagine how you would implement objects and their instance data.